# How to fix alignment on ordered list after using CSS to remove the dot after each number

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am creating a rules page for a game, and the design specs have the rules in an ordered list without the period after each number:

1 Rule one
2 Rule two
3 Rule three

I removed the dot using this code:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  
  ol > li {
    counter-increment: customlistcounter;
  }
  
  ol > li:before {
    content: counter(customlistcounter) " ";
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    width: 3em;
  }
  
  ol:first-child {
    counter-reset: customlistcounter;
  }
```

But now when the rules text reaches the second line, the text starts directly underneath the number instead of underneath the beginning of the first line of text.

1 this is what I want
to happen

2 this is what is actually
happening

Just in case it's helpful, here's the relevant html:

```
 <ol>
        <h2 class="uppercase title fs-500 text-mid">How to Play</h2>
          <li class="fs-400">
            Red goes first in the first game.
          </li>
          <li class="fs-400">
            Players must alternate turns, and only one disc can be dropped in each turn. 
          </li>
          <li class="fs-400">
            The game ends when there is a 4-in-a-row or a stalemate.
          </li>
          <li class="fs-400">
            The starter of the previous game goes second on the next game.
          </li>
        </ol>
```

I tried to adjust it with margins and padding, but either it ended up overflowing or doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`@counter-style` at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) lets you define counter styles that are not part of the predefined set of styles.

You can style the number with the `::marker` pseudo-element.

BTW, it is invalid to have `h2` as a child of `ol`. You'll need to apply margin and/or padding for the desired styling to match the padding of `ol`.

```css
@counter-style no-decimal-point {
  system: extends decimal;
  suffix: '';
}

::marker {
  font-weight: bold;
}

Ol {
  list-style: no-decimal-point;
}

li {
  padding-inline-start: 3em;
}
```

```html
<h2>How to Play</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Red goes first in the first game.</li>
  <li>Players must alternate turns, and only one disc can be dropped in each turn.</li>
  <li>The game ends when there is a 4-in-a-row or a stalemate.</li>
  <li>The starter of the previous game goes second on the next game.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <ol>
    <h2 class="uppercase title fs-500 text-mid">How to Play</h2>
      <li class="fs-400" data-value="1">
        Red goes first in the first game.
      </li>
      <li class="fs-400" data-value="2">
        Players must alternate turns, and only one disc can be dropped in each turn. 
      </li>
      <li class="fs-400" data-value="3">
        The game ends when there is a 4-in-a-row or a stalemate.
      </li>
      <li class="fs-400" data-value="4">
        The starter of the previous game goes second on the next game.
      </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
   list-style: none;
   margin-left: 0px;
}

ol > li::before {
   content: attr(data-value) ' ';
}
```

Note: `:before` has two colons: `::before`